# VBA Selection based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

My code returns with an error. The result is as wished, but the error message is rather annoying. How can I get rid of this?

```
Sub SELECTIE_VERZUIM()

Dim Cval As Variant
Dim Rng1 As Range
Cval = Sheet4.Range("A16").Value
Set Rng1 = Sheet4.Range("D1:T" & Cval).Select

End Sub
```

> **Run-time error '424':**
>   Object required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
Sub SELECTIE_VERZUIM()

    Dim Cval As Variant

    Cval = Sheet4.Range("A16").Value

    Sheet4.Range("D1:T" & Cval).Select

End Sub
```

Also, you should avoid using `Select` in VBA